# "Element is not visible" message when trying to view test step in Cypress

Tags: cypress

**Current behavior:**
I run cypress tests and they pass. The UI will display the page the last test visited. When I expand each test to display the steps, I try to click on each step in the test body. For example, get, find, click. The UI goes blank, completely white and it does not highlight the page that particular step visited or the button the step clicked on. There is an icon indicating the element is not visible.

Image 1

[image: 1]

#### Desired behavior

I watched the cypress tutorials on youtube and it appears the UI should highlight, for example, the button that was clicked. Or, if I get on the get step, it should highlight the element that was retrieved

Please see example from Lesson 4 of Cypress IO's recent tutorial video:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHXsm.png)

Notice the UI displays the page and there is no icon indicating the element is not visible.

Code:

#### Test code to reproduce

```
describe("home page", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000")
    cy.clearLocalStorage();
  })

  context("Hero section", () => {
    it("the h1 contains the correct text", () => {
      cy.getByData("hero-heading").contains(
        "Testing Next.js Applications with Cypress"
      )
    })

it("the features on the homepage are correct", () => {
  cy.get("dt").eq(0).contains("4 Courses")
  cy.get("dt").eq(1).contains("25+ Lessons")
  cy.get("dt").eq(2).contains("Free and Open Source")
})
  })

  context("Courses section", () => {
    it("Course Testing Your First Next.js Application", () => {
      cy.getByData('course-0')
        .find('a')
        .eq(3)
        .click()
  cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/testing-your-first-application')
})

it("Testing Foundations", () => {
  cy.getByData('course-1')
    .find('a')
    .eq(3)
    .click()
  cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/testing-foundations')
})

it("Cypress Fundamentals", () => {
  cy.getByData('course-2')
    .find('a')
    .eq(3)
    .click()
  cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/cypress-fundamentals')
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I too am not sure about the reason behind (still trying to figure it out) but I solved my issue by adding `.should("be.visible")` to my element and now the icon disappeared from the Cypress tab and I can hover over individual test steps and view the selection.

```
it("the h1 contains the correct text", () => {
  cy.getByData("hero-heading")
    .should("be.visible")
    .contains("Testing Next.js Applications with Cypress")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that *also* stumbles across this issue... I found [this answer](https://%20https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-testing-course-app/issues/12#issuecomment-1542616115) to the problem straight from the Cypress folks.

tldr;

"This is stemming from the a behavior that NextJS has, in which it sets the body of the document to be hidden until the app is fully hydrated in dev mode. Sometimes the tests can complete their execution before the body is set to be visible, which is why when they are selected they are showing as hidden. You can get around this by making sure the div tag that the next app is mounted to is visible right after doing a cy.visit like so:"

```
cy.visit("http://localhost:3000")
cy.get("#__next").should("be.visible")
```